# Is $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ equivalent to $\lim_{n\to 0} (1 + n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm asked to solve following limit:

> $$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+2x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

According to the textbook, the answer to the limit above is $e^2$. So far the only definition of $e$ that I saw was: $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$. But in our case, x is approaching $0$. I tried to take a guess and assume that:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}} = e $$

If we let $a = 2x$, then $x = \frac{a}{2}$ and 
$$(1+2x)^{\frac{1}{x}} = (1+a)^{\frac{1}{a} \cdot 2}$$

And thus 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+a)^{\frac{1}{a} \cdot 2} = e^2$$

But well, is $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n = \lim_{n\to 0} (1 + n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

If you pick very small number and plug it into $(1 + n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$, it indeed approaches 2.71828.

So the question is: Is $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ equivalent to $\lim_{n\to 0} (1 + n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yes it is: simply call $x=1/n$

Comment: @Crostul I think the OP is interested in a proof of that. At the end of the day $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ is just a notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. The first being that the definition of $e$ may be defined as $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ as a limit over natural numbers, while $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}(1+x)^{1/x}$ is a limit over real numbers. Secondly, the latter limit involves $x<0$, while $\frac1n>0$ for sufficiently large $n$. Thus, the issues must be resolved by:

1. Proving that $\displaystyle e=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$ holds as a limit over real $x$.
2. Proving that $\displaystyle e=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$ holds as a limit over real $x$.

The first bullet is easily managed with the squeeze theorem assuming some monotonicity:

$$\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^n\le\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\le\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}$$

where $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$ is $x$ rounded down. These follow from $a^x<b^y$ when $1<a<b$ and $x<y$. One can then rewrite the bounds as

$$\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{-1}\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\le\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\le\left(1+\frac1n\right)\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$$

and then the limit follows over the reals by the squeeze theorem.

We can then prove the limit as $x\to-\infty$ is also $e$ by substituting $x\mapsto-x$ to get

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1x\right)^{-x}$$

Since we have $\displaystyle\left(1-\frac1x\right)^{-1}=1+\frac1{x-1}$, this becomes

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{x-1}\right)^x$$

which can easily be shown to equal $e$.

Hence we've shown that

$$e=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$$

follows as a limit over the reals, and thus we have

$$e=\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+x\right)^{1/x}$$

by substituting $x\mapsto1/x$.

Answer (score 0):

If you write $m=1/n,$ then as $n\to\infty,$ we have $m\to 0,$ so that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{(1+1/n)^n}$$ becomes $$\lim_{m\to 0}{(1+m)^{1/m}}.$$ The latter has the same form as $$\lim_{n\to 0}{(1+n)^{1/n}}$$ expect for a trivial change of variable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In fact, the *definition* of $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ is $\lim_{x\to0^+}f\left(\frac1x\right)$ for $f$ right-continuous at $0$. While the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits cannot be used directly here, it's a simple exercise to show the above definition agrees with the usual definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ for a sequence $a_n$. (Similarly, $\lim_{n\to-\infty}f(n):=\lim_{x\to0^-}f\left(\frac1x\right)$ for $f$ left-continuous at $0$.)